# tilde above letter without changing font

Tags: accents, tilde

I am writing a paper and am using a template where the author's names are in capitals, such as:

```
\textsc{Robert Robertson$^1$\thanks{Corresponding Author: robert@gmail.com},  James Jameson$^1$, Will Williamson$^2$}\\
```

I would like add a tilde over one letter, for example the 'm' in Jameson. Whichever way I try this (`\˜m`, `\tilde{m}`, `\bfmath{\tilde{m}}`), I either get an italic lowercase letter or a normal font lowercase letter.

Is there a way to do this whilst keeping the formatting?

EDIT: More code below -------------------

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib} 

\usepackage{lipsum} % Package to generate dummy text throughout this template

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics

\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{multicol} % Used for the two-column layout of the document
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} % Custom captions under/above floats in tables or figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{float} % Required for tables and figures in the multi-column environment - they need to be placed in specific locations with the [H] (e.g. \begin{table}[H])
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF

\usepackage{lettrine} % The lettrine is the first enlarged letter at the beginning of the text
\usepackage{paralist} % Used for the compactitem environment which makes bullet points with less space between them

\usepackage{abstract} % Allows abstract customization
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % Set the "Abstract" text to bold
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape} % Set the abstract itself to small italic text

%\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
%\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} % Roman numerals for the sections
%\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}} % Roman numerals for subsections
%\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape%\centering%
%}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
%\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyfoot{} % Blank out the default footer
\fancyhead[C]{High-Resolution mapping of biomass and distribution of herbaceous marshes and forested wetlands in southeastern coastal Louisiana $\bullet$ \date{\today}} % Custom header text
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} % Custom footer text

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lscape} \linespread{1.5} \DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{Green}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
\definecolor{Red}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
\definecolor{GreyBlue}{rgb}{0.94, 0.97, 1.0}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{upgreek}

\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{\vspace{-15mm}\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textbf{An article on some stuff}} % Article title

\author{
\large
\textsc{Eric Ericson$^1$\thanks{Corresponding Author: robert@gmail.com},  Will Williamson$^1$, James Jameson$^2$, Stan Stanley$^3$}\\
\textsc{David Davidson$^4$, John Johnson$^2$} \\ % Your name
\normalsize \fontsize{10pt}{10pt}$^1$some institution, somewhere, USA\\
\normalsize \fontsize{10pt}{10pt}$^2$some institution, somewhere, USA\\
\normalsize \fontsize{10pt}{10pt}$^1$some institution, somewhere, USA\\
\normalsize \fontsize{10pt}{10pt}$^3$some institution, somewhere, USA\\ 
\normalsize \fontsize{10pt}{10pt}$^4$some institution, somewhere, USA\\
\vspace{-5mm}
}
\date{}
```

Comment: Please, show a minimal example. I get the expected result with `Ja\~meson`. Note `~`, not `˜` (U+02DC).

Comment: It's not really a solution I would recommend, but if you're using maths mode to write tilde/exponent/etc, you might want to use `\text` of `\mathrm` to avoid italic: `$\tilde{\text{m}}$`. But once again, It's really not the best solution...

Comment: For sure, `\tilde` is math-mode command -- don't use it in text-mode settings. For text mode applications -- e.g., regular lowercase letters, small-caps, or regular caps -- .use `\~`

Comment: @Vinzza that is no solution at all, as it is just wrong to do so. egreg's or Mico's comments show real solutions (the same one actually).

Comment: I know, that's why I said I would not recommend it... but it might not have been clear enough. I completely agree that this is not a viable solution!

Comment: \~ would not work for me. The answer from @Vinzza did work though! I will edit to include more code

Comment: @NathanThomas, *would not*? Did you try it?

Comment: @Sigur Yep, tried it again but it didn't get get me what I wanted